# Provider package in Flutter is not working in release mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Flutters provider package is not working in release mode but working fine in debug mode, I tried adding
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`but still listeners are not getting the values when we notify.

Comment: describe your problem a bit more.

Comment: please add errors if any

Comment: There are no errors while building as well as in console,Im fetching data from API while fetching i'm setting loading=true in provider and listning it as context.watch,as soon as API has returned result im setting loading =false and notifying listners but this listning is not happening in release mode but working fine in debug mode

Comment: am facing the same problem

Comment: What's your provider version in pub spec?

Comment: Are you maybe sending the request to HTTP instead of HTTPS?  HTTP needs added extra permission.

Comment: please share your code where you are using provider and notifylisteners.

Comment: This is likely completely unrelated to provider. The question is, what are you providing and how. Code sample is needed. @THEODORE You are probably better of asking a new question.

Comment: Are you sure that you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
on this file `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` instead of `android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml` or other

Comment: @SwaroopSambhayya attach your code please

Answer (score 1):

Although you didn't describe it more specifically, you can try with the below solution.

Make sure you added the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` inside `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` file. This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case by mistake I added `notifyListeners();` when it was not needed removing it fixed the problem.

```
int getItemQuantity(String? id) {
    final index = cart.indexWhere((element) => element.productId == id);
    // notifyListeners();  /// THIS LINE 
    if (index < 0) return 0;
    return cart[index].quantity ?? 0;
}
```

Check if you are getting (`setState()` or `markNeedsBuild()` called during build.) message in the console there you will find which line of your code is causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, what I did to resolve this was to run `flutter clean` on the terminal before running it on release mode and it now works exactly what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to give feedback. I was later able to resolve the issue. The error is caused when any of the Getters, setters or methods inside the provider break.  if you look closely you will see a warning in debug mode. But it somehow continues to work during debug. But it will totally stop working in release.

Mine broke because there was a double rebuild after a change between my streambuilder(BLOC) and  notifyListeners() inside the setter method. So all i did was to remove the notifyListeners() in that setter